# Matplotlib.pyplot com Django

Tags: python, django, matplotlib

Eu estou tentando inserir um gráfico através da biblioteca matlib.pyplot, porém eu consigo carregar ela somente externamente ao inserir ela dentro do django.
Quero inserir ela como uma imagem carregada, que ao receber dados do banco, ele gere uma imagem sempre que receber novos dados.

O código atual está assim: Views.py

```
def dashboard(request):
dados = Usuario.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')
x = [6, 7, 4]  # Base
y = [2, 6, 2]  # Altura

titulo = "Hello World"
eixox = "Eixo X"
eixoy = "Eixo Y"

grafico = plt.title(titulo)
grafico = plt.xlabel(eixox)
grafico = plt.ylabel(eixoy)
grafico = plt.plot(x, y)
grafico = plt.savefig('save.png', dpi=72)
return render(request, 'Usuario/dash.html', {'dados': dados, 'grafico': grafico})
```

Eu quero fazer um DashBoard com dados de Usuário e que em cima apareçam métricas sobre determinado atributo do model, mas aqui estou somente testado com dados simples e que já havia testado isoladamente.

No dash.html está assim:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %} DashBoard {% endblock %}


 {% block content %}

 <div>
 <img src="save.png">
 </div>
 <h1 class="mb-5">DashBoard</h1>
<table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
        <th scope="col">Tipo Usuário</th>
        <th scope="col">Status Usuário</th>
        <th scope="col">Nome do Usuário</th>
        <th scope="col">Login</th>
        <th scope="col">Última Atualização</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
{% if messages %}
    <ul class="messages">
        {% for message in messages %}
            <li {% if message.tags %}class="alert alert-success" {% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{%  endif %}
    {% for dados in dados %}
        <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{dados.Tipo_Usuario}} </th>
        <td>{{dados.Tipo_Status_Usuario}}</td>
        <td>{{dados.Nome_Usuario}}</td>
        <td>{{dados.Login_Usuario}}</td>
        <td>{{dados.updated_at}}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>

{% endblock %}
```

A imagem salva, mas não aparece no html

Estou há mais de 3 dias nisso, procuro em fóruns estrangeiros e aqui também, mas não consigo resolver com as soluções deles.

Comment: Em que pasta está a ser gravada a imagem?

Comment: eu estava salvando na pasta raiz mesmo, para testar se aparecia ou se pelo menos era gerado, mas não deu certo.

Comment: Eu fiquei pensando por dias, e basicamente, ele tava sendo gerado em uma pasta e eu estava chamando por outra. Como o django utiliza a pasta media para guardar as medias e eu abri uma pasta especifica pra ela. Inseri basicamente em views
    grafico = plt.savefig('media/grafico/graficos.png', dpi=1200)

e dentro do template eu coloquei
        <img src="media/grafico/graficos.png" style="width:500px;height:500px;">

Deve ser a madrugada que me trouxe essa facilidade em codificar kkk
Obrigado drec4s